# Priority queue with higher priority first in Python

Tags: python, queue, priority-queue

I need a priority queue that gets the item with the highest priority value first. I'm currently using the PriorityQueue Class from the [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) library. However, this function only returns the items with the lowest value first. I tried some ugly solutions like (sys.maxint - priority) as the priority, but was just wondering if a more elegant solution exists.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use a negative priority instead, no need to subtract from `sys.maxint`.

```
queue.put((-priority, item))
```

An item with priority -10 will be returned before items with priority -5, for example.

Comment: While this works, it honestly bothers me because that implies all other associated logic has be reversed in your head.

Comment: @blueman: then subclass the queue class and override the methods to invert the priority for you.

Answer (score 9):

You can extend the Priority Queue to keep the logic unchanged:

```
from Queue import PriorityQueue

class DualPriorityQueue(PriorityQueue):
    def __init__(self, maxPQ=False):
        PriorityQueue.__init__(self)
        self.reverse = -1 if maxPQ else 1

    def put(self, priority, data):
        PriorityQueue.put(self, (self.reverse * priority, data))

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        priority, data = PriorityQueue.get(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return self.reverse * priority, data


minQ = DualPriorityQueue()
maxQ = DualPriorityQueue(maxPQ=True)

minQ.put(10, 'A')
minQ.put(100, 'A')


maxQ.put(10, 'A')
maxQ.put(100,'A')

print "Min DQ: {}".format(minQ.get())
print "Max DQ: {}".format(maxQ.get())
```

Output:

```
Min DQ: (10, 'A')
Max DQ: (100, 'A')
```